# Absolute positioning of rasterGrobs in gtable cells

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I have been attempting to specify absolute positions for rasterGrobs in gtable cells without success. I would like to be able to have the extents of an image align to values on the y axis. The script aligns drill-core images alongside multi-sensor data plotted in ggplot2 facets. For example, a particular radiograph core image needs to have its top at 192 mm, and bottom at 1482 mm, but I want the scale to go from 0 to 1523 mm. Please see the included link for an example of what I am doing, but for simplicity I have only posted an MWE here. Is it possible to specify an absolute position for a rasterGrob inside a gtable cell?

[sample of intended output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3OzIk8_VyEMazRnT1gwT3lreUE/view?usp=sharing)

In terms of the MWE below, my only solution thus far has been to move `Rlogo.png` around using relative positions set when using `rasterGrob()`. Using `"native"` coordinates does not appear to be what I need either. Similarly, I can't make sense of the position parameters called in `gtable_add_grob()`.

```
library(png)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

# read Image
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package = "png"))

# convert to rastergrob                 
g <- rasterGrob(img, y = unit(0.5, "npc"), x = unit(0.5, "npc"))

# create plot
tp <- qplot(1:5, 1:5, geom="blank") + scale_y_reverse()

# convert plot to gtable
tt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(tp))

# add column to gtable to hold image
tt <- gtable_add_cols(tt, tt$width[[.5*4]], 3)

# add grob to cell 3, 4
tt <- gtable_add_grob(tt,g,3,4)

# render
grid.draw(tt)
```

[image: Plot produced by code above]

Did a lot of searching before coming up with this solution of using rasterGrob to add images to panels in a ggplot. Perhaps though there is a more elegant solution someone can suggest?

Comment: Noob's advice: get friendly with `gtable_show_layout(tt)`

Comment: Yeah, thanks Edward R. Mazurek. I've been using it to get new column locations right. But I can't see a bit of the measurement information with all the text overlaying. Are there some parameters that can be set to make it more readable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grob can set its position within a cell, as illustrated below

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

# quick shortcut to create a 2x2 gtable filled with 4 rectGrobs
tg <- arrangeGrob(grobs=replicate(4, rectGrob(), FALSE))

# red rect of fixed size with default position (0.5, 0.5) npc
rg1 <- rasterGrob("red", width=unit(1,"cm"), height=unit(1,"cm"))
# blue rect with specific x position (0) npc, left-justified
rg2 <- rasterGrob("blue", width=unit(1,"cm"), height=unit(1,"cm"), 
                  x = 0, hjust=0)
# green rect at x = 1cm left-justified, y=-0.5cm from middle, top-justified
rg3 <- rasterGrob("green", width=unit(1,"cm"), height=unit(1,"cm"), 
                  x = unit(1,"cm"), y=unit(0.5, "npc") - unit(0.5, "cm"), 
                  hjust=0, vjust=1)

# place those on top 
tg <- gtable_add_grob(tg, rg1, 1, 2, z = Inf, name = "default")
tg <- gtable_add_grob(tg, rg2, 1, 2, z = Inf, name = "left")
tg <- gtable_add_grob(tg, rg3, 1, 2, z = Inf, name = "custom")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(tg)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks baptiste! I'll give this a shot and report back. It seems that with this solution I'll need to use gtable_show_layout in order to actually see the plot and cell dimensions. I can't actually read a bit of the text provided though. Do you know of a way to make the gtable_show_layout more readable?

Comment: `grid.show.layout(gtable:::gtable_layout(tg), vp = viewport(gp = gpar(cex=2)))` maybe?

Comment: Thanks again @baptiste your response was a great help, although now I have many more questions that I may ask in another question. By the way, your suggestion in the above comment for adjusting cex works well.